# Which process creating cracker files?

Tags: linux, process, command-line-interface

A large number of cracker files with name FOO** are created by some of the process. I executed following command to found culprit process 
 lsof -f -F /tmp/*

But didn't found anything useful.

Is there any better way to catch culprit process.

Comment: mmm, crackers...

Comment: Out of curiousity, what do you mean by "cracker files" anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lsof |grep FOO # should give a listing of processes that are creating at that time files with the name FOO
```

if there is not output from this you may need to setup a cronjob do list every minute - I'm thinking perhaps the process is not running all the time. if nothing comes up from this look when the files were created

```
stat FOO
```

look at the owner/permissions/modification time etc. and see if something may tell you something

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the audit subsystem to track down the rogue process.

Comment: I can't use audit subsystem. Any alternate idea ?